# Cannot catch InputMismatchException in java

Tags: java, exception

When I type a none `int`, i got the output. However, the `CustomException` works well, but I have no idea why the `InputMismatchException` does not work. btw, `s` is the instance of `Scanner`.

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
>     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
>     at runMe.main(runMe.java:43)
> ```

```
int a=0;
try {
    a = s.nextInt();
    if (a < 1 || a > 9) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
} catch(CustomException cusE2) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input\n");
} catch(InputMismatchException inputE2) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input type\n");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `none int`?

Comment: Have you written your own class called `InputMismatchException`?

Comment: none int  =   not int, I didnot overwrite InputMismatchException

Comment: I think you need to show us your entire class, including imports.

Comment: What input gives you the error?

Comment: I have not been able to replicate your issue.

Comment: @Alexander I can only replicate it by writing `static class InputMismatchException extends RuntimeException {}` somewhere, but the OP says they're not doing that.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I have a feeling something is missing or OP is chasing ghosts.

Comment: You must realize that your input must be a number, or else, control won't even reach the if condition and raise an exception straight away!